# On Nuxt-Link click refresh page if same url

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-link

For example, I have a blog website, with a discover page that doesn't take any params. When you load page fetch hook calls API that randomly returns some article.

So my problem is when I'm already on the Discover page and I click discover in the Left bar I want the page to refresh.

`:key="$route.fullPath"` is not working for me because nothing is changing in the path.

Comment: You can use Vuex or emits to defining a variable that indicates the user clicks on the left bar button that you want refresh the data in current route after clicking it and then watch that variable and with every change call the refresh data handler